# Adjust legend and colours in grouped boxplots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make `grouped boxplots` with `ggplot`. The code I have generates the grouped boxplots. However, there are quite a few things that I would like to improve on the boxplot:

[image]

**1) Remove the second legend introduced by `scale_fill_manual`**

**2) Keeping the colors in my code, change the boxplot to look like the following design:**

[image]

The boxplots produced with my code do have the above transparency, but the whiskers cut through the box (does not look good). The `median` should be visible like in the above sample and whiskers should not cut through the box.

Here is what I have tried so far. The double legend is an issue and the whiskers cutting through the boxplots is another.

Sample data and code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    ## create some data.frames: this results in a list of four dfs
    createDF <- quote(data.frame(id=sample(c("NN", "SS","H"), 100, rep=T),
                                 heavy=runif(100),
                                 heavier=runif(100),
                                 heaviest=runif(100)))
    dfs <- lapply(1:4, function(i) eval(createDF))
    
    ## join and shape them
    library(reshape2)
    dat <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
    dat$dfid <- paste("df", rep(1:4, times=sapply(dfs, nrow)))
    dat <- melt(dat, id.vars=c("id", "dfid"))
    
    #-----plot
    
    ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(id, level = c('H', 'NN', 'NS')), y=value, group=interaction(variable, id), fill=variable, colour=variable)) +
      stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.6,lwd = 0.9,position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))+
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable, colour=variable),width = 0.6,lwd = 0.9,outlier.shape = NA,outlier.colour = NULL, coef = 0, 
                   position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"),alpha = 0.6,fatten = 2) +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = c(0, 0)) + 
      facet_grid(.~dfid)+ #reorder facets
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4daf4a","#984ea3","#ffff99","#ff7f00","#e41a1c"),name="")+ #  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue"))
      scale_color_manual(name = "scenario", values = c("#4daf4a","#984ea3","#ffff99","#ff7f00","#e41a1c"))+
      labs(y = "Values", x = "")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", angle = 0, face = "bold"),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
            text = element_text(size = 18),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, size = 9, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
            legend.direction = "vertical",
            legend.position = "right",
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey70"),
            panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1))+
      theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = c(0.5, .79))+
      guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1))+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())+theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 10, face = "bold"))+
      theme(legend.margin=margin(-10, 0, 0, 0))+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="white", size = 0.2),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
    #theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.0,0,0.2), "lines"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this design:
While question number 1 was easy: to remove the second legend just add `guide = "none"` in `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual`.

The second question was achieved by using `position_dodge(1)` to position the boxplots and the colors design are maybe a workaround:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(id, level = c('H', 'NN', 'NS')), y=value, group=interaction(variable, id), fill=variable, colour=variable)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar',lwd = 0.9,position = position_dodge(1))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable), colour="grey80",width = 0.6,lwd = 0.9,outlier.shape = NA,outlier.colour = NULL, coef = 0, 
               position = position_dodge(1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  facet_grid(.~dfid)+ #reorder facets
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4daf4a","#984ea3","#ffff99","#ff7f00","#e41a1c"),name="", guide = "none")+ #  scale_fill_manual(values = c('1' = "black", '2' = "white", '3' = "darkred", '4' = "lightblue"))
  scale_color_manual(name = "scenario", values = c("#4daf4a","#984ea3","#ffff99","#ff7f00","#e41a1c"), guide = "none")+
  labs(y = "Values", x = "")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", angle = 0, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, size = 9, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position = "right",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey70"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1))+
  theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = c(0.5, .79))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=1))+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())+theme(legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 10, face = "bold"))+
  theme(legend.margin=margin(-10, 0, 0, 0))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="white", size = 0.2),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the trick to question 1. I think the sample design I showed is made in plotly.  The workaround adds a grey outline to the boxes? What about using the same colours as the box and filling the box with same colors? Then reduce the transparency of the boxes? This causes the whiskers to cut through the box. Also, can you make the space for each group distinct from within group spacing?

Comment: Note also that I used ‘position_dodge2’ because ‘H’ in the x-axis has only one box plot in the group in my actual data. Thus  dodge2 makes the boxes equal size across all groups.